# NSPredicate multiple conditions no results

Tags: ios, objective-c

i'm using a NSPredicate to filter an array in my searchbar. This is my code which works perfectly.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.name contains[cd] %@",searchText];

filteredArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[storesArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
```

The problem is i want to add a second condition as the name which is the address. How can i do this? I've tried this, but then none of the predicates are working.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.name contains[cd] %@",searchText];
NSPredicate *predicate1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.address contains[cd] %@",searchText];


NSPredicate *fullPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[predicate, predicate1]];
filteredArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[storesArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:fullPredicate]];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [OR comparison operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html):

```
NSPredicate *predicate = 
    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.name contains[cd] %@ OR SELF.address contains[cd] %@", searchText, searchText];
```

Comment: Or the `AND` comparison operator if you need both conditions to be met.